# filter a selected line from textbox vb.net 2008

Tags: .net, text, filter, textbox

I want to extract from the textbox if the text is written like this:

> Title: DLF is now introducing amazing DLF_CITY_CENTRE in Gurgaon
>
> Description: PROPERTY DETAIL The first mall of the National Capital
>   Region (NCR) is situated in Gurgaon along the Mehrauli Gurgaon Road.
>   It also houses the 3-screen multiplex, DT Cinemas, and features a host
>   of restaurants such as Moti Mahal   COMMON AMENITIES SPECIFICATIONS
>   * The development has a total lettable area of 260,000 square feet and is currently anchored by the Lifestyle Department Store.
>   * The mall also provides parking for up to 700 vehicles.   For More Detail Please contact us…!!!! Mobile: 09990000000
>   Website: www.timberwala.com

And I want the only text which is in after Title, Description, Location, mobile, website
and the content is dynamic.

Q:I am able to get the text in a textbox, but now I want to get the data from title, description, etc. to multiple textboxes like

title to textbox1
description to textbox2

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use regular expressions to break the string apart and parse it into the invidual fields you desire -- You don't have to use regular expressions, as you could use .NETs native string manipulations (such as SubString, etc) but Regular Expressions are much more flexible and powerful.

I would recommend this thread for a primer on regular expressions: [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

I can't vouch for RegEx Buddy which they mention in the thread, but I have indeed found Expresso VERY handy in working out expressions.  It is free and available at: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Example using .NET string methods:

```
Dim Title As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Title:") + 6, TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Description:") - 6).Trim()
```

(Really Simple) Example using Regular Expressions (make sure to Import System.Text.RegularExpressions)

```
Dim Description As String = Regex.Split(TextBox1.Text, "Description:", RegexOptions.Multiline And RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)(1).Trim
```

Comment: thanks got your help art but i need some further help so can u give me your facebook id?